# Which organism has the sharpest vision?

Tags: zoology, vision

Which organism has the sharpest vision in terms of distance and spectrum. Please propose any other useful measure.

Comment: You might also want to consider field of vision and acuity.

Comment: you may want to pick a metric, humans have decent acuity but see a much smaller portion of the spectrum than non-mammals. Almost any bird see's more of the spectrum than almost any mammal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A good measure for "sharpest vision" is known as acuity of vision. Visual acuity denotes the ability to perceive detail and resolve temporal motion. This metric informs how sharp or blurred an organism perceives its surroundings. There is software which helps quantitate this metric with visual examples.

The following example shows how a comparison of different organism's perception may look like, visually:

[image: Comparison of human, hummingbird, butterfly and bee vision]

When we broadly compare the various vision systems of organisms based on acuity, a plot below may give one a better perspective:

[image: Acuity across different organisms]

From the above, it is noted that eagles have specially evolved eyes with high visual acuity. Of note, the Australian wedge-tailed eagle can see 8 times more detail than humans can. Interestingly, their eyeball have the ability to squeeze and elongate similar to a zoom lens on a camera.

Reference:

1. [Wedge-tailed Eagle Factsheet](https://www.wildlife.vic.gov.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0017/115343/Wedge-tailed-Eagle.pdf)
2. [Visual Acuity and the Evolution of Signals](https://www.cell.com/trends/ecology-evolution/fulltext/S0169-5347(18)30052-1?_returnURL=https%3A%2F%2Flinkinghub.elsevier.com%2Fretrieve%2Fpii%2FS0169534718300521%3Fshowall%3Dtrue)
3. [AcuityView Software](https://besjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/2041-210X.12911#:%7E:text=AcuityView%20renders%20an%20image%20in,information%20available%20to%20that%20viewer.)

Comment: So I guess without glasses, my vision is as good as that of a butterlfy.

Answer (score 5):

[This paper](http://deepblue.lib.umich.edu/bitstream/2027.42/23426/1/0000374.pdf) suggests that bats have a comparatively high depth of focus.

It's believed that [butterflies](http://landsat.gsfc.nasa.gov/education/compositor/em.html) (depending on species) have the widest visual spectrum.

Comment: Don't hawks have exceptional range?

Comment: Birds of prey - hawks, falcons, eagles, vultures - along with some owls all have exceptional vision.

Comment: I thought bats were blind.

Comment: How about the Mantis Shrimp?

Answer (score 0):

### T-rex

As an archosaur it sees a wider portion of the spectrum than mammals and it has the largest eyes known in terrestrial vertebrates, and eye size correlates well visual acuity, so the largest eye should be close the the highest acuity.

So yes Jurassic park could not be more wrong about T-rex vision, T-rex would see better than the humans trying to hide.

[https://www.karger.com/Article/Fulltext/357830#:~:text=Thus%2C%20as%20eye%20size%20increases,eye%20length%20(table%201).](https://www.karger.com/Article/Fulltext/357830#:%7E:text=Thus%2C%20as%20eye%20size%20increases,eye%20length%20(table%201).)

https://www.academia.edu/13386081/Evolution_Beyond_the_rainbow